# Safari 12 Extensions and NativeMessaging

Tags: safari-extension, safari-app-extension

With the release of Safari 12, Safari will no longer support NPAPI plugins. My use case is to be able to launch a java application located on a client from a browser extension which I can currently do in Chrome and Firefox with NativeMessaging. From my reasearch, I do not see a way to do this in Safari 12. The closest I can see is their "Safari App Extension" project but this looks like it requires that you package up your native app with the extension and distribute it through the App Store. I am not at all a Mac developer so I am looking for some advice. Does anyone know if Safari supports my use case?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a extension that will download our dmg app with the native code.And run the dmg app after it is getting downloaded.
Then we can place our extension in the safari extension gallery.

We have implemented it in the similar way where our extension look for the json file which in turns download the DMG app that we have kept in the server.

Comment: By going through https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/124 . It seems we have temporary solution by keeping our extension in the safari extension gallery with few tweaks.
But eventually we will have to move to App based extension as from the next release of MacOS and Safari they will stop the support from safari extension gallery also.